# How to get 'sum' less than one value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

Test statement  ：

```
create table #t
(
  isid int primary key identity(1,1),
  amount decimal(18,2)
)
go

insert into #t values(23.43)
insert into #t values(213.43)
insert into #t values(523.3)
insert into #t values(23.4)
insert into #t values(263.23)
insert into #t values(223.43)

drop table #t
```

How to get 'sum' less than one value（ex.500） order by isid?
there has one statement

```
select * from #t as a where exists(select 1 from #t where isid<=a.isid having sum(amount)<500)
```

but it has a bug.
When first value more than 500 and second value is negative number.

ex:

```
insert into #t values(503.43)
insert into #t values(-13.43)
```

the result will only has one value(-13.43).

Comment: Can you maybe try and explain your problem better? I'm not sure I understand...

Comment: So, in the case that the first value is over 500, you want to return that row or do you want no rows?. And that is not the only way to obtain an inconsistent behaviour, what happens if there is another negative value that makes your `SUM` to be less than 500?, for instance, if you add `INSERT INTO #t VALUES(-800)` there

Comment: I’m sorry for my poor english.   in the case if the first value is over 500（520） and second value is negative（-30），i want to get the two rows。 520+（-30）=490<500.  if the first value is over 500（520） and second value is not negative, i want to no row return.

Comment: Are you asking how to find the sum of `amount`, adding values in order by `isid`, and stopping before the sum exceeds a limit value, e.g. 500?  It sounds like a running total with a limit.

Comment: Yes.This is what I mean。

Comment: @ChuiFeng So, what happens if in your first test data you insert a `-800` as the last row?, what should be the result?

Comment: @Lamak  if in my first test data you insert a -800 。"select * from #t as a where exists(select 1 from #t where isid<=a.isid having sum(amount)<500)"   will return 3 rows。this result is correct。first value is -800 second is 1023.43 third is -213.43

Comment: @ChuiFeng No, if in your first data you insert a `-800` as the last value

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server is this for? IN SQL-Server 2012, some useful functions have been added that can simplify this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, I think we can generate running totals for all values in our set and pick the maximum "isid" that has a sum less than 500.

```
    create table T
    (
      isid int primary key identity(1,1),
      amount decimal(18,2)
    )
    go

    insert into T values(503.43)
    insert into T values(-13.43)
    insert into T values(5.00)
    insert into T values(1.00)
    insert into T values(55.00)

SELECT isid
FROM T
WHERE isid <= 
(
  SELECT MAX(B.isid)
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
      T1.isid,
      T1.Amount,
      SUM(T2.Amount) AS SummedAmount
      FROM T T1
      INNER JOIN T T2 ON T2.isid <= T1.isid
      GROUP BY T1.isid, T1.Amount
      HAVING SUM(T2.Amount) < 500
    ) B
)
```

Here is a SQLFiddle:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/968af/4

Comment: in this test data,i want to get isid (1,2,3,4) .not(2,3,4)

Comment: Please see the edit I just made.  We just need to select everything that is less than the MAX(isid)

Comment: thank you very much .this is what i want.  Others,Can you recommend some books about sql .i want to study it well

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get the isid with the largest cumulative sum less than 500, assuming that the isid's are numbered sequentially with no gaps:

```
select minisid - 1
from (select MIN(isid) as minisid
      from (select *, (select SUM(amount) from #t t2 where t2.isid <= t.isid) as cumsum
            from #t t
           ) t
      where cumsum >= 500
     ) t
```

If you want to return no rows in the second case, then add the clause:

```
where minisid > 1
```

Comment: But the `minisid > 1` isn't taking into account if that value is less than `500`, you'll always filter it. I don't think that this is what he wants

Comment: @Lamak . . . The intent is to filter out any rows in the second case.  The initial sum starts over the limit.  There is no "value before".  Without the `where` it would return 0 (an invalid id).  With the `where`, it returns no rows.

Comment: Even if the intent on the second case was to return no rows (op said on a comment that he actually wants the two rows), it is assuming that you know beforehand that the first value is over 500, but I think that the expected query should work without this previous knowledge

Comment: @Lamak the result is 3. I want to get isid and amount  detail like the  result in image.

Answer (score 0):

@Lamak what happens if in your first test data you insert a -800 as the last row?  [image: the result img]

Comment: Even though this shouldn't be an answer, I'll ask for clarification. Please, I'm saying that the `-800` should be the **last** row, not the first, it should be at the end of your inserts. And it doesn't need to be a `-800`, just a value that brings the whole sum to a value less than `500`

Comment: whole sum to a value less than 500.

Comment: Yes, what happens in that case?, I know that the whole sum value would be less than 500, that's what I said, I want to know what would be the result in that case

Comment: eg1(only amount). row1  510 ,row2  -16, row3   5,row4  9   i want rows(1,2,3,4) because (510+(-16)+5+9)500

Comment: eg2(only amount). row1 510 ,row2  16, row3 5,row4 9 i want there is no rows return, because 510>500

Comment: eg3(only amount). row1 50 ,row2 150, row3 290,row4 20 i want rows(1,2,3) because (50+150+290)<500

Comment: eg3. row1 510, row2 16, row3 5, row4 9, row5 -120. What rows do you want?

Comment: @Lamak  thank you very much . i got the anwser from Michael Bowersox. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL-Server version, you can use the enhancement of the **[`OVER ()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddcef3a6-0341-43e0-ae73-630484b7b398)** clause:

```
WITH cte AS
( SELECT
      isid,
      SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY isid
                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                 AND CURRENT ROW
                       ) AS sum_amount
  FROM t
)
SELECT MAX(isid)
FROM cte
WHERE sum_amount < 500 ;
```